# pyqtgraph real time plotting using start button created in Qt designer

Tags: python, qt, plot, designer, pyqtgraph

Please I appreciate any help !!

I have design a MainWindow in Qt Designer with just a simple Graphic View widget and two push button: one to start real time signal plotting (e.g. sine wave) and the other to stop the real time plotting. The name of this file is "PPGview.ui".

Then, I have created the PPGview_ui.py file in Spyder where I load the PPGview.ui configuration. Whenever I press the start button I would like to update a plot in in my Graphic View widget but instead it opens another window and does not plot anything anyway.

I have proved plt.plot(time,y) and .setdata(time,y) and nothing

```
"""
Example: main window
Created on Thu Dec 21 12:07:49 2017
Ref:https://www.youtube.com/watchv=xC9zV3QVqVs&list=PLjARR1053fYm1tNe3lMEqn5acADPxSWTY    
@author: Kevin Machado
"""

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox  
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import ctypes
from time import time
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg


class visualWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        loadUi("PPGview.ui",self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Principal User Interface')
# Window Size propeties
        self.showMaximized()
# Buttons configuration
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startButton1)
# brings a box when closing the UI
        Resolution = ctypes.windll.user32
        Resolution_ancho = Resolution.GetSystemMetrics(0)
        Resolution_alto = Resolution.GetSystemMetrics(1)
        left = (Resolution_ancho / 2) - (self.frameSize().width() / 2)
        top= (Resolution_alto / 2) - (self.frameSize().height() / 2)
        self.move(left, top)
# function when closing        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        resultado = QMessageBox.question(self, "Salir ...","Seguro desea salir?",
                                         QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if resultado == QMessageBox.Yes: event.accept()
        else: event.ignore()
 # function to store the signal
    def getdata(self, tsignal):
        f=10
        sAmpli = 1.0814
        zeroDes = 0.5413

        sR= zeroDes + sAmpli * (0.05*np.sin(2*np.pi*tsignal*3*f)
        + 0.4*np.sin(2*np.pi*tsignal*f) + 0.25*np.sin(2*np.pi*tsignal*2*f+1))

        return sR

    def startButton1(self):
        timestamp= time()
        pw = pg.plot()

        while True:           
            stamp = time() - timestamp
            y = self.getdata(stamp)
            pw.setData(stamp, y, pen=(255,0,0))
            pg.QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
_visualWindow = visualWindow()
_visualWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Here is the .ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>794</width>
    <height>533</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">QMainWindow{
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

QPushButton{
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
color:rgb(176, 176, 0);
font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
}</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QMainWindow{
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="GraphicsLayoutWidget" name="graphicsView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>771</width>
      <height>381</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="startButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>290</x>
      <y>460</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Start</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="stopButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>440</x>
      <y>460</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Stop</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>794</width>
     <height>18</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>GraphicsLayoutWidget</class>
   <extends>QGraphicsView</extends>
   <header>pyqtgraph</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: show your .ui, please

Comment: Thank you for reply. There it is

Comment: Thanks for the reply again @eyllanesc. I got it, I think it was just because I was trying to plot points instead of a list of them. I did this simple example in my repository. https://github.com/LatinAmericanProgramer/PyQtGraph-real-time-plotting-RTgraph-modified-version